# how to encrypt parameters passed in url in django template

Tags: django, templates, encryption

I need to encrypt id passed from template to view in django.
Actually, user_id have to be encrypted in url so no one can get the id passed in url
this code.

```
<tr>    
{% with user_id=item.user_id %}
#user_id have to be encrypted                                   
<td><center><a href="{% url "accounts" user_id %}">{{ item.Company_name }}</a></center></td>
{% endwith %}
```

i've been looking for a while but i didn't find how to encrypt parameter in template.

Comment: I think you should think about using slugfield in user model.

Comment: Does it really need to be encrypted? If you do proper checks in the view, it shouldn't matter if people try to use someone else's ID, the checks would prevent them from accessing the page anyways.

Comment: Well most major web platforms do not try to hide userid's its really an inconsequential information if your permissions are well defined/implemented

Answer (score 2):

I think Paulo is confusing encryption with signing. Look at [Pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) for encryption functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't if `encrypt` is exactly what you meant. I mean, encrypting a string using say, `md5` will make impossible to decrypt the string for you on the server side. For this purpose you should go with `encode`, like using `base64` encoding system. This will replace the id with an encoded string but someone `savvy` may notice this and decode the string in your urls.

What you're trying to accomplish here is **security through obscurity** which is not recommended. You can apply this technique but you'll be better adding even more security in your code like permissions and stuff like that.

For encoding your user id, you can add this method to your `Item` class:

```
class Item

    ...

    def encoded_id(self):
        import base64
        return base64.b64encode(str(self.user_id))

    def decode_id(self, id):
        import base64
        return base64.b64decode(id)

    ...
```

That way you can do this in your views:

```
<tr>    
{% with user_id=item.encoded_id %}
#user_id have to be encrypted                                   
<td><center><a href="{% url "accounts" user_id %}">{{ item.Company_name }}</a></center></td>
{% endwith %}
```

and you will have your urls with the `id` encoded in base64.

Pay attention to my warning before. **You should never rely only on this, this is a valid practice but keep in mind that the encoding can be reversed.**

Hope this helps!